# Connecting S7 to home wifi brings the wifi down

Tags: networking, internet, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge, wifi-direct

I have a WiFi network at home and several devices connect to it fine. As soon as I connect my phone to the wifi, all other devices and my own get disconnected after a couple of minutes. After this the wifi becomes unavailable for hours. I can still use the internet with a wired connection but the WiFi is gone. I have tried switching wifi channels and any other settings but nothing works (including restarts). Sometimes if I power down my phone the wifi comes right back up and all other devices can connect again, sometimes it takes a few hours.

I haven't been able to key any pieces of this together. My phone, which is a galaxy S7 edge is clearly the cause but I can't understand why.

Comment: Which Wi-Fi channel did you switch to?

Comment: The router has 13 channels. I tried them all